# Rails 3 - Delayed_Job - For all emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, actionmailer

Is there a way using a Rails 3 initializer to make all application emails sent out by delayed_job by default?

I tried something like this:

```
# config/initializers/delayed_mailer.rb
class ActionMailer::Base
  Delayed::Worker
end
```

But it errors with:

execution expired

Comment: @Shadwell, not a duplicate. That's an outdated GEM.

Answer (score 0):

Can you override `ActionMailer::Base.deliver` to do `Delayed::Job.enqueue self`?  Also, take out Delayed::Worker, I think that's run via the rake task to pop things off the queue.  Also, if you're going to monkey patch things, make note of it in initializers or make a patches directory that is read by an initializer.